# c++ - array of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array, shared-ptr

### Context:

I try to avoid vectors and replace it with smart pointers **as an exercise**.
The goal is to benefit from smart pointers to avoid memory leaks without relying on vectors, because that is what I want to try now.

The codes below is just a mean to be easily understood.

I want my c++ code to work.

Update : I would like to stick as much as possible with raw c'ish style for IO: please no std::string or c++ streams in general.

### The codes:

C version (working):

```
typedef struct{
    char ** my_arr;
} MyInputs;

...
MyInputs *Doc = malloc(sizeof *Doc);
*Doc->my_arr = malloc(sizeof (*Doc->my_arr) * 2);
Doc->my_arr[0] = malloc(10);
Doc->my_arr[1] = malloc(10);

// Yes, that is stupid to alloc 10 bytes and use only 6 or 5. That is for the example.
memcpy(Doc->my_arr[0],(char*)"Hello\0",6);
memcpy(Doc->my_arr[1],(char*)"Cool\0",5);

printf("%s %s \n",Doc->my_arr[0],Doc->my_arr[1] );
...
```

C++ version (attempt):

```
typedef struct {

    std::shared_ptr<char*>my_arr;

}MyInputs;

...

std::shared_ptr<MyInputs> MainDoc (static_cast<MyInputs*>(malloc(sizeof (*MainDoc))),free); 

std::shared_ptr<char*> Z (static_cast<char**>(malloc(sizeof (**MainDoc->my_arr) * 10)),free); 
std::shared_ptr<char> Z[0](static_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof (char *) * 10)),free); 
memcpy(Z[0].get(), (char*)"salut\0", 6);

cout << Z[0] << endl;

...
```

### The obvious:

In the c++ version, the compiler complains about Z and Z[0] being the same and that there is not match for operator [] in the cout.
Well, well, well...

Any ideas that could make the c++ code work that way ? (and again, I know about vectors).

Comment: Use `make_shared<>` instead of `malloc()`. That's not going to work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: `make_shared` doesn't allow you to specify a custom destructor, which you'll need to do if you want to (ab)use the pointer to manage an array.

Comment: Even the C-code is wrong: sizeof **Doc->my_arr is 1 (a single character)

Comment: Correct overlooked. Edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you insist on using the wrong tool for the job, then you'll want each inner pointer to also be a smart pointer:

```
shared_ptr<shared_ptr<char>> my_arr;
```

You can't simply use `malloc` to create an array of non-trivial types like `shared_ptr`; use `new`:

```
my_arr.reset(new shared_ptr<char>[10], [](shared_ptr<char> * p) {delete [] p;});
```

Then you can assign or reset the elements. `shared_ptr` doesn't support `[]`, since it's generally not used for arrays, so use `get()` to get a pointer to the first element:

```
my_arr.get()[0].reset(new char[10], [](char * p) {delete [] p;});
```

Or just replace this gibberish with something sensible

```
std::vector<std::string> my_arr {"Hello", "Cool"};
```

Comment: Yes, finally the vector is by far the best solution.. Thanks Mike

Comment: I know it's hard for some of you to understand, but there are circumstances where you may not want the overhead of STL containers. C++ is commonly used for embedded and low-power environments where every byte of memory and every clock cycle is significant. So try to temper the condescension -- it's not helpful.